# How to pull the user profile image?

Tags: rest, ajax

Using the _api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager I've gathered the information needed to display my user profile image and presence.

pInfo is a variable that contains the property information needed to put a string like the one below together, but I'm having some syntax issues.

pInfo.Email will give me bgates@azurenow.com

I need some assistance getting string my src together so it looks like below:

```
src="/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname=Bgates%40azurenow.com&url=https%3A%2F%2Fazurenowgc-my.sharepoint.com%3A443%2FUser%2520Photos%2FProfile%2520Pictures%2Fbgates_azurenow_com_MThumb.jpg%3Ft%3D63547340551&t=63547340551"
```

Here I haven't quite grasped how to put it all together:

```
src="/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname="' + pInfo.Email + '" + "&" + "'+pInfo.PersonalUrl +'" alt="' + pInfo.AccountName + '"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code before in SharePoint 2007:

```
ServerContext CTX = ServerContext.GetContext(this.Site);

UserProfileManager UPM = new UserProfileManager(CTX);

string resultado = "<table><tr><td>Cuenta</td><td>Foto</td><td>Web</td></tr>";

foreach (UserProfile UP in UPM) 
{

resultado += "<tr><td>" + UP["Accountname"].Value + "</td><td>" + UP["PictureUrl"].Value + "</td><td>" +  UP["PersonalSpace"].Value + "</td></tr>";

}
```

Comment: That looks clean and simple, but I'd like to get what I have to work.

Comment: Could you please paste the value of SRC your code is generating right now?

Comment: Original results like this: "https://azurenowgc.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname="

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I will make note of the clean code you provided and test it out. By introducing another variable, I was able to build the necessary string. New Variable Introduced:
var myurl = "/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&amp;accountname="+ pInfo.Email +'&url='+ pInfo.PictureUrl; Then, all I had to do was add the new variable like so: src="' + myurl + '" alt="' + pInfo.AccountName + '" />

Comment: It is solved? Glad to read this :-)

Comment: Use something like this:
var authorPicUrl = webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&amp;accountname=" + encodeURIComponent(username);
//the part after accountname is optional.